# Angular material autocomplete options show event

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'd like to catch the event that occurs when the options are displayed on an angular material autocomplete control. Such as the following from the material docs:

[Autocomplete documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples)

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are asking for an onTypeAheadDropDownOpen event for the mat-autocomplete drop-down.

If Yes. Typically, I understand that the onClick event of the mat-input field inside the mat-autoComplete is same as this one.

If you are attempting to change values in the drop down or do animations etc in the drop down, there are more direct ways to do it instead of being bothered with this.